# HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request when uploading large file using AJAX

Tags: asp.net, http, asyncfileupload

I am getting bad request from ASP.Net website on submitting the large file 2GB using AJAX.

My HTTP runtime setting
`<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600"/>`

Please help.

Web.Config
`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="microsoft.web.services3" type="Microsoft.Web.Services3.Configuration.WebServicesConfiguration, Microsoft.Web.Services3, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="psDevDataConnectionString1" connectionString="" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000" />
      </webServices>
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600"/>
    <membership defaultProvider="xplProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="xplProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="LocalSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="10" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/sysError.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/infoCollector.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" clientIDMode="Static"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="DocImage" verb="GET,POST" path="DocImage.axd" type="DotnetDaddy.DocumentViewer.DocImageHandler, DocumentViewer"/>
      <add name="pngs" verb="*" path="ClientPortals/images/*" type="Project.UserInterface.ClientPortals.image" preCondition="managedHandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <modules>
      <add name="UploadModule" type="RTE.UploadModule,RichTextEditor"/>
      <add name="CuteEditor.UploadModule" type="CuteEditor.UploadModule,CuteEditor"/>
    </modules>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/scenter.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967296"/>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="PageInspector:ServerCodeMappingSupport" value="Disabled"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="ServiceSoap1"/>
        <binding name="sms2SOAPbasicHttpBinding"/>
        <binding name="sms2SOAPbasicHttpsBinding">
          <security mode="Transport"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="sms2wsHttpBinding">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="sms2wsHttpBindingSecure">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://api.authorize.net/soap/v1/Service.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceSoap" contract="ArbApiSoap.ServiceSoap" name="ServiceSoap"/>
      <endpoint address="http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/Soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sms2SOAPbasicHttpBinding" contract="cdyneSMS.Isms" name="sms2SOAPbasicHttpBinding"/>
      <endpoint address="https://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/SecureSoap" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sms2SOAPbasicHttpsBinding" contract="cdyneSMS.Isms" name="sms2SOAPbasicHttpsBinding"/>
      <endpoint address="http://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/WS" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sms2wsHttpBinding" contract="cdyneSMS.Isms" name="sms2wsHttpBinding"/>
      <endpoint address="https://sms2.cdyne.com/sms.svc/WS" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="sms2wsHttpBindingSecure" contract="cdyneSMS.Isms" name="sms2wsHttpBindingSecure"/>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="AWSSDK" publicKeyToken="9f476d3089b52be3" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.55.0" newVersion="2.3.55.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <microsoft.web.services3>
    <messaging>
      <executionTimeoutInSeconds value="300" />
      <maxMessageLength value="524288000" />
    </messaging>
  </microsoft.web.services3>
</configuration>
```

`

Answer (score 4):

`maxRequestLength` is in **Kilobyte** not byte so 2147483647 Kilobytes is about 2000 GB that's a lot. 2GB = 2097152 KB. Try to change it to 2097152

On the other hand, `maxAllowedContentLength` is in bytes.

It is recommended to place both those values in web.config.

> The maxRequestLength indicates the maximum file upload size supported by ASP.NET, the maxAllowedContentLength specifies the maximum length of content in a request supported by IIS. Hence, we need to set both maxRequestLength and maxAllowedContentLength values to upload large files.

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097152" executionTimeout="3600"/>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Thanks Ronaldinho for suggetion
But after adding requestFiltering tag, I am always getting 500.

Comment: Added Config file in post. Please help

Comment: So did you change `maxRequestLength` to 2097152 which equals to 2GB (I think this is the max value in ASP.NET) and `maxAllowedContentLength` to 2147483648?